# Importing SurveyMonkey survey into CognitoForms

Tags: cognito-forms, surveymonkey

Is it possible to export surveys from a SurveyMonkey account, and import them into a CognitoForms account?  I wasn't able to find any info in the help pages of either service.

For my specific use case, here are my account types:

- SurveyMonkey: SELECT Annual
- CognitoForms: Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) currently supports automatic import of forms from Wufoo only.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/l/wufoo-alternative

We will consider other import tools in the future.  The main reason we chose Wufoo first was their large presence in the market and lack of innovation since they were acquired by Survey Monkey.  Also, the fact that 100% of Wufoo form features translated to Cognito Forms was a bonus too!